# On Wordpress, Woocommerce, and AffiliateWP, modify the email-order-details.php to have the name of the affiliate in the email template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate

I am pretty new to Wordpress and Woocommerce and I am want to know how to customize the 
`woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php` file to add the name of the **Affiliate** into the default email template so that i can see who is the affiate just by checking the notification email.
I am using *AffiliateWP* to manage affiliates.
If someone can help, I will be gratefull.
Here is the original source code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Order details table shown in emails.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>

<h2>
    <?php
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a>';
        $middle = "\t\tJuliano\t\t";
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = '';
    }
    /* translators: %s: Order ID. */
    echo wp_kses_post( $before . $middle . sprintf( __( '[Order #%s]', 'woocommerce' ) . $after . ' (<time datetime="%s">%s</time>)', $order->get_order_number() . $middle, $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
    ?>
</h2>

<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            echo wc_get_email_order_items( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                $order,
                array(
                    'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
                    'show_image'    => false,
                    'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                    'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                    'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
                )
            );
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <?php
            $item_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

            if ( $item_totals ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $item_totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Note:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( nl2br( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ) ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$order->get_billing_first_name()` you can get the first name.

And with `$order->get_billing_last_name()` you get last name.

Sou you can try adding this

```
<div>Hello, <?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name();>? <?php echo $order->get_billing_last_name(); ?> </div>
```

before of

```
<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir!
My other question is: "Is there any sort of documentation where I can find what are the attributes 
and methods of the '$order' variable for example?".

Comment: Yes there are all the strings https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html dont forget to accept my answer. @JosoaJulianoRAHAJAHARIMANGA